# Postgres entries per week, for every week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to return the count of entries per week, for every calendar week. My current code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, date_trunc('week', occured_on) AS week
from incidents
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', occured_on)
ORDER BY date_trunc('week', occured_on);
```

This returns:

```
count  |        week         
-------+---------------------
     1 | 2009-09-28 00:00:00
     2 | 2009-10-19 00:00:00
     6 | 2009-10-26 00:00:00
     3 | 2009-11-02 00:00:00
     6 | 2009-11-09 00:00:00
    22 | 2009-11-16 00:00:00
```

Skipping a week where no incidents occurred. How do I get the count of 0 for that week, showing the total number of entries for each calendar week, rather than each week an incident occurred?

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by generating the series of weeks and then using `left join` before the aggregation.  The following generates the series using CTEs.  This is not necessary, but I think it shows the logic being used:

```
with dates as (
      select min(date_trunc('week', occured_on)) as startw,
             max(date_trunc('week', occured_on)) as endw
      from incidents
     ),
     weeks as (
      select generate_series(startw, endw, '7 days') as week
      from dates
     )
select w.week, count(i.occured_on)
from weeks w left outer join
     incidents i
     on date_trunc('week', i.occured_on) = w.week
group by w.week;
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8fe1a/4).

Comment: Best and most readable solution I've seen to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  my_weeks.week_number  AS week , IFNULL(i.count,0)
from 
(
 SELECT generate_series (1,54,1) AS week_number
) my_weeks
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, date_trunc('week', occured_on) AS week
  from incidents
  GROUP BY date_trunc('week', occured_on)
) i
ON my_weeks.week_number = i.week
ORDER BY my_weeks.week_number ;
```